# Homework from studies! - module computation of an approximating function

Tags: polynomials, homework, approximation

Polynomial approximation

The aim of the task: to write a program in the form of a module in the Mathematica® machine code
computation of an approximating function F (·) for an approximated hypothetical function f (·), whose
the data has errors. The data is generated using the code:

```
Clear [rv, a, b, n, h, nd, fnc1, empDtF];
rv: = RandomReal [{- 0.5, 0.5}];
n = 25; a = -1; b = 2; h = (b - a) / n; 
nd = Table [a + h k, {k, 0, n}];
fnc1 [x_] = 2 x Cos [E ^ (- 2 x)];
empDtF = Table [fnc1 [nd [[s]]] + rv, {s, Length [nd]}];
```

The input parameters of the module are:
a) left end a of the interval `[a, b]`;
b) the right end of the b compartment `[a, b]`;
c) number of nodes of the approximating grid;
d) degree m of the approximating polynomial;

The output data of the module are:
a) approximating polynomial;
b) charts in one layout
empirical data, graph of empirical function, graph of approximating function;
c) mean square error approximation.

**I am asking for help in the correct calculation, I do not know if I am going the right way.**
[image]

---

my current code (I don't know if it is correct)

```
Clear[rv, a, b, n, h, nd, fnc1, empDtF];
n = 25; a = -1; b = 2; h = (b - a)/n;
rv := RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}];
wzli = Sort[RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}, n]];
dtImp = RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}, n];
valueF = dtImp ;
nd = Table[a + h k, {k, 0, n}];
fnc1[x_] = 2 x Cos[E^(-2 x)];
empDtF = Table[fnc1[nd[s]] + rv, {s, Length[nd]}];
mtrxVdm = Table[If[nd[[i]] == 0 && j == 0, 1, (nd[[i]])^j], {i, Length[nd]}, {j, 0, n}];
mtrxVdm // MatrixForm ; 
grpFi = Plot[fnc1[x], {x, a, b}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.004]}];
pOXY = Table[{nd[[k]], valueF[[k]]}, {k, Length[nd]}];
grpPOXY = ListPlot[pOXY, PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0, 0.7, 0]];
Show[ grpFi, grpPOXY]
```

Comment: Please post the actual code in copy-pastable format. Images do not do well for such purposes.

Comment: my current code (I don't know if it is correct)

Comment: Just for the record, what is the meaning of the "Graduation from studies" in the title? Is it related to this question being a final homework of some sort? If yes, please update the tags to include the homework-related one.

Answer (score 1):

Your question sounds like your professor wants you to use a module, i.e., `Module[]`.  In Mathematica, a module is like a function or a subroutine in other languages.

I'm not entirely sure what is meant by "number of nodes of the approximating grid". For "mean square error approximation" I'm grabbing the mean square error from the ANOVA table for the fit. Check help files for `LinearModelFit[]` to see other options. Below might be close to what you are looking for.  Perhaps you can modify it to do what you need; if not, leave a comment and I can try to fix it.

`a` is index of first element in region to fit.
`b` is index of last element in region to fit.
`c` is "number of nodes of the approximating grid" (currently unused)
`m` is degree of polynomial for fit.

```
ClearAll[x];
MyFitModule[data_, a_, b_, c_, m_] := 
 Module[{fitBasis, fit, fitFun, fitPlot},
  fitBasis = Table[x^n, {n, 0, m}];
  fit = LinearModelFit[data[[a ;; b]], fitBasis, x];
  fitPlot = 
   Show[ListPlot[data[[a ;; b]]], Plot[Normal[fit], {x, a, b}]];
  {Normal[fit], fitPlot, Last@fit["ANOVATableMeanSquares"]}
  ]
```

```
MyFitModule[empDtF, 1, 10, 20, 2]
```

[image]